# ASP.NET MVC UpdateModel() parameter conversion woes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

A forewarning: I've relatively new to MVC and its paradigm and to some of its inner workings, but I'm pretty comfortable with it. This is my second ground-up MVC application and I'm a little stumped with how to solve a "problem" one of our testers found.

What the users get is an edit screen given an effective date for daily LIBOR rates that come from Treasury (percentages). The rates are always between 0 and 100 and consequently I've tried to constrain that range using a `RangeAttribute` in the metadata for one of my domain objects. I've specified the range like so:

```
[Required, DisplayName("Published Rate"), Range(typeof(decimal), "0", "100")]
public object PublishedRate { get; set; }
```

Notice that I'm passing in string values as the `RangeAttribute` does not have an overloaded constructor that takes decimals. This seem to work great until a user goes and enters something out of the ordinary, like:

> "0.000000000000000000000000000000001"

This causes `UpdateModel()` to fail; the `ModelState` shows this error (three times for the same ModelState value, curiously):

> The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Decimal' failed.

Digging into the errors reveals the cause. The first line below is what's reported by the validation for the field. I found it curious that this did not bubble up to the *model* validation errors (i.e. did not show up in the summary validation list for the model):

> "0.000000000000000000000000000000001 is not a valid value for Decimal."
>   "Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal."

`System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType()` and `System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom()` are throwing the exceptions.

A user is never going to enter a value such as this, but I wouldn't mind knowing if there are any mechanisms built in to MVC that could or will prevent this (server-side, that is). There doesn't seem to be an issue with numbers like the following, it only seems to break with ones that are very small.

> "0.555555555555555555555555555555555"

At the end of the day I really only need 9 digits of precision. The database table column backing these values is a `decimal(9,6)`. I know I could implement a custom model binder for my model and manually collect the values from the Request, but there's got to be something a little easier, such as a custom `FilterAttribute` or something that can correct the value before its attempted to be bound to the model, I'm just not sure what, and am looking for suggestions.

I seem to recall reading about some issues with trying to constrain decimal values using a `RangeAttribute` but I can't recall the issue. Perhaps you MVC gurus out there can shed some light on the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a couple of hours of head banging I settled on the following custom model binder for decimals. It makes sure that all decimal values are parseable before binding them.

```
public class TreasuryIndexRateDecimalBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var providerResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (providerResult != null)
        {
            decimal value;
            if (!decimal.TryParse(providerResult.AttemptedValue, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out value))
            {
                // TODO: Decide whether to show an error
                // bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "error message");
                return 0m;
            }
            return Math.Round(value, 6);
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

The binding is set up in `Application_Start()` to register it for all decimal values.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new TreasuryIndexRateDecimalBinder());

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Unless somebody comes along with a more interesting approach I think I'll stick with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regex attribute to contain the decimal to a precision of 9.  This would also allow you to add a custom message when the Regex fails, such as "Your value may have a maximum of 9 places after the decimal." or something similar.  Also if you have client side validation enabled, the Regex will work in both client and server side validation.